# How to code a gif grid for a search using the Giphy API?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple questions...

I have an HTML form for a search bar that I'm trying to send to the Giphy API but I can't get the string entered by the user on the input tag when I code an `addEventListener("click")` for the submit button.

HTML:

`<form id="input_bar">
    <input type="text" name="search_string" id="search_string">
    <button type="submit" id="search_submit">Submit!</button>
</form>`

JS:

`const searchBar = document.getElementById("search_string");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("search_submit");`

`submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function getResults(submitBtn) {
    var searchResult = fetch("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + submitBtn + "&api_key=" + apiKey)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
});`

The fetch URL sent is

> {...}/search?q=**[object%20M…seEvent]**&api_key={...}

What am I missing?

Also, I have no idea how to append the `response.json` to a `<div id="results_grid"></div>` to return the gif grid.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the button object to the API instead of the search bar value.

Change this:

```
searchResult = fetch("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + submitBtn + "&api_key=" + apiKey) .then(function(response) { console.log(response); }) });
```

To this:

```
searchResult = fetch("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + searchBar.value + "&api_key=" + apiKey) .then(function(response) { console.log(response); }) });
```